# Avoid "Can't make ...class... into type number." error

Tags: xcode, applescript, nspopupbutton

```
property myValue : ""
property myPopUp : missing value
on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    tell standardUserDefaults() of current application's NSUserDefaults
        registerDefaults_({myValue:myValue})
        set myValue to objectForKey_("myValue") as text
    end tell
    myPopUp's selectItemAtIndex_(myValue - 1)
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_
on myButtonHandler_(sender)
    set myValue to (myPopUp's indexOfSelectedItem) + 1 -- This line may be mistake
end myButtonHandler_
on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    tell standardUserDefaults() of current application's NSUserDefaults
        setObject_forKey_(myValue, "myValue")
    end tell
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
end applicationShouldTerminate_
```

I wrote this code, but I get this debug error:

```
 (Project Name)[42733:303] *** -[AppDelegate myButtonHandler:]: Can’t make «class ocid» id «data optr00000000C7FFFFFFFFFFFFFF» into type number. (error -1700)
```

Can anyone tell me how to get my code fixed? How do I avoid the error?

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and then select it as the correct answer so that other users suffering from this same problem will find this solution

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that I should do it. I posted my solution as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by myself.

```
property myValue : ""
property myPopUp : missing value
on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    tell standardUserDefaults() of current application's NSUserDefaults
        registerDefaults_({myValue:myValue})
        set myValue to objectForKey_("myValue") as text
    end tell
    myPopUp's selectItemAtIndex_(myValue - 1)
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_
on myButtonHandler_(sender)
    set myValue to (myPopUp's indexOfSelectedItem()) + 1 --Here is the mistake
end myButtonHandler_
on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    tell standardUserDefaults() of current application's NSUserDefaults
        setObject_forKey_(myValue, "myValue")
    end tell
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
end applicationShouldTerminate_
```

I should have written indexOfSelectedItem() but I wrote indexOfSelectedItem.